# No shared Links available in iOS 7 Safari

Tags: safari, ios

New with iOS 7 is a "Shared Links" tab in Safari. I have twitter accounts setup on my device (TweetBot shows them). However I don't see any content in the Shared Links tab. Just this message:

> No Shared Links
>
> Links shared by your contacts from select social networks will appear
> here.

How do I link my twitter account in Safari so that content appears here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Twitter** and link your account there. Once installed, and linked, if you open the `Bookmarks` tab in Safari, you will see `Bookmarks`, the `Reading List`, and `Shared Links`. If you have logged in properly, your Shared Links will appear here.

[image: Shared Links screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I already had my account setup, however after restoring from iCloud I had to recreate my account for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; the update wiped out many passwords, and this is what's causing minor problems.

To get Twitter to work on Safari 7, go to **System Preferences > Internet Accounts > [your Twitter account]**. The account should be there as one of your accounts, and your password is likely gone - just retype it and save. Give Safari a few seconds to catch on the password exists again, and the shared links should go live in a matter of a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, logout of twitter and back in again in your settings.